# An error occurred during conversion seam text to html

Tags: html, xhtml

I am using the following rich:editor control to create a new message. I choose Heading 1 under Format drop down and entered some text and persist the entry. But when I try to edit the message it fails with the following error on load. How should I fix this issue?

An error occurred during conversion seam text to html

```
        <s:decorate template="/layout/edit.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="label">Message</ui:define>
                <rich:editor required="true" id="messageField" theme="advanced" useSeamText="true" viewMode="visual" autoResize="true" value="#{newsHome.instance.message}">
                    <f:param name="theme_advanced_buttons1" value="newdocument,separator,cut,copy,paste,separator,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,separator,hr,removeformat,visualaid,separator,sub,sup"/>
                    <f:param name="theme_advanced_buttons2" value="bullist,numlist,separator,outdent,indent,blockquote,separator,undo,redo,separator,link,unlink,anchor,separator,image,cleanup,help,code,separator,forecolor,backcolor"/>
                    <f:param name="theme_advanced_buttons3" value="fontselect,fontsizeselect,formatselect,styleselect,separator,charmap"/>
                    <f:param name="theme_advanced_resizing" value="true"/>
                    <f:param name="theme_advanced_toolbar_location" value="top" />
                    <f:param name="theme_advanced_toolbar_align" value="left" />
                </rich:editor>
        </s:decorate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a problem we had with rich:editor whenever someone entered content with an odd number of underscores.  It was caused by [a bug in RichFaces](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-7347), and we fixed it by upgrading RichFaces to 3.3.3.